GPU Not Computing using python
ACER Laptop with RTX3070. Installed CUDA, cuDNN, Tensorflow.
Tensorflow detecting GPU.
CUDA test script detecting GPU and shows GPU stats.
Trying to run this jit script to test GPU computing but getting errors. Any help will truly be appreciated.
Script:
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
# to measure exec time
from timeit import default_timer as timer


# normal function to run on cpu
def func(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i] += 1

    # function optimized to run on gpu


@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def func2(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i] += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 10000000
    a = np.ones(n, dtype=np.float64)

    start = timer()
    func(a)
    print("without GPU:", timer() - start)

    start = timer()
    func2(a)
    print("with GPU:", timer() - start)

Error:
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" E:\Programming\Projects\CUDA\TestingGPU.py 
without GPU: 1.1927146000000448
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Projects\CUDA\TestingGPU.py", line 30, in <module>
    func2(a)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 442, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 375, in _compile_for_args
    return_val = self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 905, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 94, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 103, in _compile_core
    self.targetdescr.options.parse_as_flags(flags, self.targetoptions)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\options.py", line 41, in parse_as_flags
    opt._apply(flags, options)
  File "C:\Users\Faheem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numba\core\options.py", line 66, in _apply
    raise KeyError(m)
KeyError: "Unrecognized options: {'target_backend'}. Known options are dict_keys(['_dbg_extend_lifetimes', '_dbg_optnone', '_nrt', 'boundscheck', 'debug', 'error_model', 'fastmath', 'forceinline', 'forceobj', 'inline', 'looplift', 'no_cfunc_wrapper', 'no_cpython_wrapper', 'no_rewrites', 'nogil', 'nopython', 'parallel'])"

Process finished with exit code 1


This question is similar to: Unrecognized options: {'target'} when using @jit(target="cuda"). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Oh and by the way, the RTX3070 is not designed to perform float64 operation efficiently. It will likely be slower than a good CPU for that. You can see that here : it reach 0.32 TFlops which is a bit slower than what my (older) 5 years-old mid-end cheaper i5-9600KF CPU consuming twice less power. Your GPU is only good for its high memory throughput and simple precision.

Hi Jerome. Thanks for the reply. I looked at url you provided about setting target / target_backend. In my case i simply removed the target thing completely and it worked. Here is code:
@jit
def func2(a):
for i in range(100000000):
a[i] += 1
Output:
without GPU: 11.673872300001676
with GPU: 0.19822520000161603
Process finished with exit code 0

Thanks for the reply. I looked at url you provided about setting target / target_backend. In my case i simply removed the target completely and it worked. Here is code:
Previous Code
@jit(target_backend=cuda)
def func2(a):
    for i in range(100000000):
        a[i] += 1

Modified Code
@jit
def func2(a):
    for i in range(100000000):
        a[i] += 1

It worked. The CPU and GPU computation outputs are:
without GPU: 11.673872300001676
with GPU: 0.19822520000161603
Process finished with exit code 0

Well, "It worked" depends on your expectations. This code still runs on your CPU (njit is only for CPUs). The speed-up comes from the (CPU) JIT compilation of the Python code (which is usually interpreted due to CPython and so often slow, unless the code is vectorized, which means it calls some compiled native code).

A way to vectorize the code is simply to use Numpy: np.add(a, 1, out=a). This code is equally fast to func2 on my machine in your case (ie. 4.6 ms in both cases with a.size == 10_000_000). Numpy as the benefit to be faster when the function is called for the first time since Numba compile the function lazily at runtime (which takes 72 ms on my machine).

Adding target_backend='cuda' has no impact on performance on my machine. It is just ignored. Maybe you just measured the compilation time?

Hi Jerome, I stand corrected. You are right. Being new to Python and CUDA, i had the impression that func2 with @jit sends code to GPU and that is why it was completed way to fast. I did further research and found the same as u mentioned. Thanks once again.
